Removing watermark before converting the pdf into docx format using convertapi
I'm currently attempting to convert a PDF into DOCX format using convertapi. While the conversion process itself is successful, I've encountered an issue. The PDF I'm working with contains a watermark on each page, and this is causing formatting issues in the resulting DOCX file. Is there a way to remove the watermark before converting the PDF into the DOCX format?
I tried removing the watermark but it did not worked

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

We are working on watermark removal API, please provide your PDF file to us.
